# Facebook Post with picture hosted on public CDN

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook is seemingly blocking any image that I reference which is backed by a CDN.

1. Is this true?
2. Is there a way to get around this?
3. Is there documentation out there that states what you can and can not reference in the "Picture" argument of a post?

Comment: we encountered the same problem today but only for photos hosted on Facebook CDN. Twitter CDN seems to work.

Comment: Facebook has always blocked photos on their CDN, but I have lately seen some instances where they block other CDNs. Interestingly enough, they give an error when you try to post something on the FBCDN, but they just won't post the picture when it's on another CDN.

Comment: Yea, I just want to see some guide to what I can and can not post... ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, facebook prevents you from using images from it's CDN in posts, shares etc.
2. Yes. You can use a intermediate page that takes the CDN image and copy it on-the-fly. My script does exactly that (see below)
3. There is no official documentation regarding the use of CDN images.

`http://sportplatform.sportengland.org/videos/image.php?src=http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/602487_10150174597139971_1671360825_n.jpg`

Basic structure is `http://sportplatform.sportengland.org/videos/image.php?src={image url}`. You can add an image into the URL, include one on Facebook's CDN. However, this is a commercial script that I created so I don't advise on using it directly. Think of it more like a proof of concept.

Comment: If you want the script. Feel free to email me via my website.